# How do I debug my emacs crash on Windows?

Tags: emacs, windbg

I use emacs on windows (at work) and on linux (at home). On the windows machine, I'm using emacs 23.1 (from here: ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/windows/emacs-23.1-bin-i386.zip). It just crashed right now. Recently, I've taken a healthy interest in debugging on windows (using WinDbg), so I really want to try my hand at this ready-made crash :) Can someone tell me where (or if at all) I can get the symbol files (.pdb) for emacs for windows? On linux, I compile my emacs from source so symbols aren't really a problem...

Answer (score 0):

Also, with an emacs crash, the problem is quite likely somewhere in the elisp code (relatively little of emacs is written in c), in which case emacs already has source debugging for elisp built in.

Between ielm, the stack trace tool, edebug, debug-on-error, m-x apropos and the ability to modify and reload definitions at runtime it has pretty comprehensive debugging without needing to use an external tool. An external tool will actually won't be very useful for elisp stuff.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to diagnose hangs (100% CPU) - unresponsive?  I found this question because it seems an external debugger is the only way to interrupt it.

Comment: I'm getting emacs 23 on Win7 hanging on exit (I suspect my use of org-mode and leaving it running while I sleep the laptop and wake it daily), so I'm interested in the same thing.  PDBs would be great to use VS or WinDbg - and while I could build from source, I'd rather try to the prebuilt one.  But if there aren't symbols available, I may have to build or try Justin's other debugging suggestions and see if they can work on hangs.

Comment: Found another suggestion - toggle debug-on-quit then hit C-g when it hangs and supposedly we should get a backtrace that might help diagnose the hang.  Or try starting emacs from terminal/cmd and might get console output when trying to quit.

Comment: See also http://yoo2080.wordpress.com/2013/10/03/what-to-do-when-emacs-hangs-freezes-or-crashes/ - tips on using debug-on-quit and debug-on-entry under windows.   Or  http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/elisp/elisp_16.html - good info on debugging elisp.

Comment: FWIW - Actually, crashes occur far more often in the Emacs C code than in the Lisp code, I believe.

Comment: Actually, Elisp should **never** crash Emacs. Only C code can do that. When Elisp encounters an error, it just terminates execution of the current command and returns control to the editor command loop. Any other behaviour is, once again, a bug in the C code.